# cc1plus: out of memory when building dlib

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install dlib in order to install the python package face_recognition. While doing so I ran into the following error:

```
ubuntu:~/dlib$ sudo python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating dlib.egg-info
writing dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /home/ubuntu/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/ubuntu/dlib/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=yes -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.7")
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
-- pybind11 v2.3.dev0
-- Enabling AVX instructions
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct - found
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header - found
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
-- Checking for module 'cblas'
--   No package 'cblas' found
-- Checking for module 'lapack'
--   Found lapack, version 3.10.3
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found LAPACK library
-- Found ATLAS BLAS library
-- Looking for cblas_ddot
-- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
-- Looking for sgesv
-- Looking for sgesv - not found
-- Looking for sgesv_
-- Looking for sgesv_ - found
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Found Python with installed numpy package
-- Numpy include path '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
-- LTO enabled
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/dlib/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j1'
Scanning dependencies of target dlib
[  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/tensor_tools.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/widgets.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/drawable.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/style.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX static library libdlib.a
[ 71%] Built target dlib
Scanning dependencies of target dlib_python
[ 73%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_rank_trainer.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/decision_functions.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/other.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/basic.cpp.o

cc1plus: out of memory allocating 8388608 bytes after a total of 54640640 bytes
CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/build.make:230: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/basic.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/basic.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 238, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 24, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 119, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 155, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04 via AWS EC2 free trial so I don't have much memory (1GB), could that be the issue since it mentions an issue allocating memory? I can't really do much about that at the moment, is there any way I can make it install without using so much if this is the problem? Or if this is not the issue, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Can I allocate more virtual memory or something?

Comment: yes, it looks like the compiler is out of memory

Answer (score 2):

Went for a higher memory/CPU server (t3.medium) temporarily and did the following to get it to work:

```
apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .
cd ..
python3 setup.py install

pip3 install face_recognition
```